# Frequency Spectrum with c++

Tags: frequency-spectrum, spectrogram, c++

[image]I have written a script to plot the frequency spectrum of a sinusoidal signal with c++. Here are the steps
1-Applying Hanning window
2-Apply FFT using fftw3 library
I have three graphs: Signal, Signal when is multiplied to Hanning function, and the frequency spectrum. The frequency spectrum looks wrong. It should have a pick at 50 Hz.Any suggestion would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i;
double y;
int N=50;
double Fs=1000;//sampling frequency
double  T=1/Fs;//sample time 
double f=50;//frequency
double *in;
fftw_complex *out;
double t[N];//time vector 
double ff[N];
fftw_plan plan_forward;

in = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

 for (int i=0; i< N;i++)
 {
    t[i]=i*T;
    ff[i]=1/t[i];
    in[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform
    double multiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/(N-1)));//Hanning Window
    in[i] = multiplier * in[i];
  }

  plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

  fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

  double v[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

    v[i]=20*log(sqrt(out[i][0]*out[i][0]+ out[i][1]*out[i][1])/N/2);//Here I have calculated the y axis of the spectrum in dB

    }

   fstream myfile;

   myfile.open("example2.txt",fstream::out);

   myfile << "plot '-' using 1:2" << std::endl;

   for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)

    { 

      myfile << ff[i]<< " " << v[i]<< std::endl;

    }

 myfile.close();

 fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
 fftw_free ( in );
 fftw_free ( out );
 return 0;
  }
```

I have to add that I have plotted the graphs using gnuplot after inserting the results into example2.txt. So ff[i] vs v[i] should give me the frequency spectrum.

Here are the plots: [image]  Frequency Spectrum and Sinusoidal time Window respectively:
[image]

Edit: After applying the changes to frequency sampling, this is the graph I got:[image]
Edit: The first graph is the plot for frequency spectrum vs time

Comment: You probably don't want to plot it on a logarithmic scale.  Values very close to zero (as you have around zero frequency) will completely obliterate the actual useful signal.

Comment: Even when I change v[i] to v[i]=sqrt(out[i][0]*out[i][0]+ out[i][1]*out[i][1]); the result looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing something odd with your frequency axis. This:

```
t[i]=i*T;
ff[i]=1/t[i];
```

should probably read:

```
t[i]=i*T;
ff[i]=Fs*i/N;
```

The frequency axis you have now is nonlinear. The FFT generally generates linearly spaced frequency samples.

Comment: Only Fs * i/N  works..Fs * i does not render any good result.

Comment: I have added the new plot above.

Comment: Yes, thats much more like it.

Comment: But there is something wrong because now I try to plot time vs v[i] to get the spectrogram and the graph looks funny. I will ass it to my question above.

Comment: `v[i]` is a frequency-domain variable. It makes little sense to try to plot it against time.

Comment: Isn't it a definition of spectrogram? Frequency vs time?

Comment: The "spectrum" is frequency vs power / amplitude.  [The "spectrogram" is a completely different thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) that shows how the frequency content varies with time.

Comment: I know. That is why I said frequency vs time. If I plot v[i] vs t[i] (spectrogram) in my program I get a funny graph. I show them  in the below post.

Comment: That's a completely different question. You need to break up the signal into blocks, take the FFT of each block (and then its magnitude).  And then accumulate each FFT block into a matrix.  Then you will have time (the center time of each block), frequency (the FFT index of each block) and amplitude the value in each bin of the FFT.

Comment: I have breakup my sinusoidal signal into N bins. I have taken the FFT of each bin with FFTW3 and calculated the magnitude with v[i]. I just thought if I have the frequency spectrum right then by changing t to f I will have a spectrogram.

Comment: No. You haven't broken your signal into $N$ bins.  From what I see in the code above, you have *sampled* your signal into $N$ bins.  What you need to do to get a spectrogram is to break those $N$ samples into $B$ blocks of a given length (e.g. if $N$ is 8192, use $B$ of 128).  And then take the FFT of each 128-length of the $N/B$ blocks.  Then your `v[i]` will become `v[i][j]` where `i` is the block number from 1 to $N/B$ and `j` is the frequency bin from 0 to 127.

Comment: So I should slice out a 'chunk' of samples and that would give me blocks?and then apply windowing and FFT on those blocks?

Comment: Yes. That will give you a matrix of values, rather than just a vector. And if you're after a plot of time-vs-frequency, that's one way to get it.

Comment: I have put the spectrogram code together follwing your steps and put it here:http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25608/spectrogram-of-a-sinusoidal-signal-with-c

Comment: The plot does not look right, could you please take a look at it and let me know the errors.